# How to use a pdf/ps as background image in ggplot2?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, overlay

I'm trying to overlay a semi-transparent ggplot map on a map (vector graphic) I created with WMS (Geoserver).

I can import the pdf in R with grImport package (commands PostScriptTrace, readPicture and pictureGrob). But now i'm lost. I would like to overlay the ggplot image on the pdf background image. Can I specify ggplot to use the grob as a background image?

Thanks to baptiste for pointing me into the direction of "annotation_custom()".
With his help i've managed to create a more minimal example for my question:

```
library("cluster")
library("lattice")
library("ggplot2")
library("grImport")

sink("test.ps")
cat("%!PS\n")
cat("/petal {\n")
cat("newpath\n")
cat("0 0 moveto\n")
cat("-5 10 lineto\n")
cat("-10 20 10 20 5 10 curveto\n")
cat("5 10 lineto\n")
cat("closepath\n")
cat("0 setgray\n")
cat("fill\n")
cat("} def\n")
cat("20 20 translate\n")
cat("5 {\n")
cat("petal 72 rotate\n")
cat("} repeat\n")
cat("showpage")
sink()
PostScriptTrace("test.ps")
test.ps.xml <- readPicture("test.ps.xml")
test.grob <- pictureGrob(test.ps.xml)

# following the example from 'Importing Vector Graphics: The grImport Package for R' by Paul Murrell I can test the graphic and add the .ps to a lattice plot
xyplot(V8 ~ V7, data = flower,
  xlab = "Height", ylab = "Distance Apart",
  panel = function(x, y, ...) {
    grid.symbols(test.ps.xml, x, y, units = "native", size = unit(5, "mm"))
  }
)

# ... but I would like to add the .ps as a background image to a plot with ggplot2
polygon.df <- data.frame(
  id = 1,
  x = c(-60,60,60,-60,-60),
  y = c(0,0,175,175,0)
)
ggplot() + annotation_custom(test.grob)+
  geom_polygon(data=polygon.df, aes(x=x, y=y), alpha=.2, fill="blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-70, 70), expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-10, 185), expand = c(0,0))
```

The ps-graphic is however not plotted to the ggplot. I'm sure I'm missing out on something quite trivial.

EDIT: The following DOES show the grob:

```
qplot(x=polygon.df$x, y=polygon.df$y)+ 
annotation_custom(test.grob)
```

The folling DOES NOT show the grob:

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data=polygon.df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
annotation_custom(test.grob)
```

I don't quite understand why it dows show the grob with qplot(), but doesn't with ggplot().

Comment: you can place a grob with `annotation_custom`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I already tried it but failed. I added a minimal example. If I add '+ annotation_custom(test.grob)' to the code nothing changes to the plot

Comment: it seems that these grobs are not behaving as standard, unfortunately

Comment: Thanks, I tested my grob with some example from "Importing Vector Graphics: The grImport Package for R - Paul Murrell".     `library("cluster")    
xyplot(V8 ~ V7, data = flower,  
  xlab = "Height", ylab = "Distance Apart",  
  panel = function(x, y, ...) {  
    grid.symbols(PSflower, x, y, units = "native",  
    size = unit(5, "mm"))  
  })`

Comment: The above code displays the grob correctly. I'm however not able to display even simple grobs within ggplot with `annotation_custom`.  
I'm afraid I don't quite understand how to use `annotation_custom`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, baptiste. I've changed my example based on your suggestion to use annotation_custom. Also I've replaced my quite large pdf-file with a more minimal ps-file so it's not needed to download data for the minimal example.

Comment: btw you can output multiple lines with `cat()`, and give it a file argument directly.

Answer (score 0):

annotation_custom is quite buggy, maybe it cannot deal with pictureGrob. You could try the following trick to add a grob to the gtable,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)

p <- qplot(1,1) + theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill=NA))
g <- ggplotGrob(p)

pos <- gtable_filter(g, "panel", trim=FALSE)$layout
g <- with(pos, gtable_add_grob(g, test.grob, t, l, b, r, z-1))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]